# How to guarantee an API only accepts requests from a desktop application?

Tags: security, spring-security, cryptography, desktop-application

Similar to how CORS works in ensuring only websites with a specific domain can make API calls to a server. How can you ensure an API only accepts calls from a desktop application. If you have hardcoded secret keys on a desktop executable, can someone still access those keys?

Comment: This has been asked in different ways many times. The short answer is that this is not possible in a secure way, you can't authenticate an application, you can authenticate users. Also in the vast majority of cases, this risk is way overestimated, and a solution is usually not actually necessary.

Comment: you can't, never trust the client. Its as easy as that.